# Is there any api in libclang to simpilfy BinaryOperator

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, clang, libclang

I want to do a transform on my code, it simplifies the binary operator e.g. "1+ a+ 2" to "a+3", so is there any api in libclang can do such things?

Comment: I would expect the Clang to do this as part of its code generation process, so what would you achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

If you are referring to Clang as the C/C++/ObjC frontend to LLVM, then there's no such API I know of - this is not the kind of thing a front-end is designed to do.

LLVM core (which is a part of Clang if you refer to it as a complete compiler) can do these kinds of things, but then there's no API to translate it back to the source language.

I think your best bet to do something like this is to write a Clang-based tool to modify the source (see [LibFormat](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibFormat.html) as an example). However, I recommend re-thinking why you need this in the first place - since this will happen anyway during compilation. You won't gain any performance, and you might make the code less readable.

And in general, if you want to add a certain transformation for performance reasons, and it currently does not happen during compilation, the correct way to do so is not to modify the source program but to [write an LLVM pass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html) which will run during the compilation and perform the fix. Clang is not involved in that.